# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous (after using np.logical_and)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, markov-chains

I am trying to iterate over an array (which is 500x100) and sum up the total number of times zero appears next to zero, or zero appears next to one, or zero appears next to two etc. (for all combinations of 0, 1, and 2)*.

I have working code that does this fine for an array with one row, however, when I try and do it with more than one I get the 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous' error which I thought I could fix using np.logical_and but this has not worked.

*NB if the end of the first row ends in 0 and the second row starts with 0, this should not be added to the sum of the number of times zero follows zero (this applies for any combination). Also, 0, 1 and 2 refers to weather conditions.

This is the code which gives me the error:

```
example = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

total_rainy_given_sunny = 0
total_sunny_given_sunny = 0
for i, j in enumerate(example[:-1]):
    if np.logical_and(example[i] == 0, example[i+1] == 0):
        total_sunny_given_sunny = total_sunny_given_sunny + 1
    if np.logical_and(example[i] == 0, example[i+1] == 1):
        total_rainy_given_sunny = total_rainy_given_sunny + 1

print("Σ(S|S): ", total_sunny_given_sunny)
print("Σ(S|R): ", total_rainy_given_sunny)
prob_sunny_given_sunny = total_sunny_given_sunny / (total_sunny_given_sunny + total_rainy_given_sunny)
print("P(S:S): ", prob_sunny_given_sunny)
```

This code is working:

```
example = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
total_rainy_given_sunny = 0
total_sunny_given_sunny = 0
for i, j in enumerate(example[:-1]):
    if example[i] == 0 and example[i+1] == 0:
        total_sunny_given_sunny = total_sunny_given_sunny + 1
    if example[i] == 0 and example[i+1] == 1:
        total_rainy_given_sunny = total_rainy_given_sunny + 1

print("Σ(S|S): ", total_sunny_given_sunny)
print("Σ(S|R): ", total_rainy_given_sunny)
prob_sunny_given_sunny = total_sunny_given_sunny / (total_sunny_given_sunny + total_rainy_given_sunny)
print("P(S|S): ", prob_sunny_given_sunny)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Look at result of the logicaland.  How many values?  `if` only works with one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I don't quite understand it though. ```if``` can work with lots of values, can it not?

Comment: @PeterCourt `if` evaluates a single boolean. That error message is actually quite simple once you know that, it all falls into place. Let me know if it still isn’t entirely obvious though :)

Comment: `if True:` not `if np.array([True, False]):`

Comment: Still lost I'm afraid. You're saying ```logical_and``` is a numpy array, and that the if statement can't handle it being true and false at the same time? For a normal if statement you can have two conditions, as seen in the working example above. Why doesn't it evaluate to false when ```np.logical_and(example[i] == 0, example[i+1] == 0)``` are not both true, like a normal ```if``` ? Sorry if I'm being dim

Comment: `np.logical_and` performs an element-wise `and` operation, i.e. `z = np.logical_and(x, y)` is equivalent to `z[i] = x[i] and y[i]` for all `i`. If you want to test if all of these evaluate to `True` then you require `np.all`, and if you want to evaluate if any one of them evaluates to `True` then you require `np.any`, both of which will reduce the array to a single boolean.